# How to Use WebGL with ArcGIS API for JavaScript 3.24

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Starting with 3.24 of ArcGIS API for JavaScript we can opt in to render **FeatureLayer** with **WebGL**.

According to ESRI This allows to display more data in the map and update the visualization of features more rapidly. To enable WebGL rendering of FeatureLayer, we need to paste the following script in the application prior to loading the ArcGIS API for JavaScript:

```
  <script>
    var dojoConfig = {
      has: {
        "esri-featurelayer-webgl": 1
      }
    };
  </script>
```

but looking at [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/grkoLL1k/1/) I am not really seeing any difference  between having the webgl or not on performance speed. Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [service](https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/ks_earthquakes_since_2000/FeatureServer/0) used in this sample is on a [10.5.1 server](https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/ArcGIS/rest/services). From the [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html)

> Support is limited to layers created from feature services hosted on ArcGIS Online. Non-hosted enterprise feature services will be supported at the ArcGIS Server 10.6.1 release. FeatureLayers created from FeatureCollections are not supported.